# How can I Get value from first picker and populate second picker?

Tags: react-native, rest, picker

i have 2  functions
one is to get the value from a REST api and populate a picker (This is a success, as it works fine) now the second picker is supposed to get value from the first picker and then call another REST api and then populate from another REST api, but this one is a proven difficulty.

How can i get the value from the first picker and use it to call another REST api which would inturn populate the second picker.

**PS** here is what i am trying to achieve, i select the country like this

[image: Screenshot-1671955057.png]

and it shows the corresponding banks in the country, but here it is not working this is what i have

[image: Screenshot-1671955072.png]

My code is looking thus :

```
import {
  ImageBackground,
  Modal,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import {Picker} from '@react-native-picker/picker';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
import BackgroundOpacity from './BackgroundOpacity';

const InternationalPayments = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [getBanks, setGetBanks] = useState([]);
  const [getCountry, setGetCountry] = useState([]);
  const [bank_name, setBank_name] = useState('');
  const [country_name, setCountry_name] = useState('');
  const [country_symbol, setCountry_symbol] = useState('');
  const [bank_code, setBank_code] = useState('');
  const [selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry] = useState();
  const [selectedBank, setSelectedBank] = useState();
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  getBanksByCountry = (symbol) =>{
    fetch(`https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/banks/${symbol}`,{
      method:'GET',
      headers:{
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer FLWSECK_TEST-72fe360edef17334f4817a17407011bb-X',
      },
    }).then(response = response.json())
      .then(responseJson =>{
        setGetBanks(responseJson.data);
        setBank_name(responseJson.data.name);
        setBank_code(responseJson.data.code);
      })
  }

  getallCountry = async () =>{
    fetch('https://webserver-migospay.onrender.com/api/location/get-country',{ //<=== This one is working fine, gets the countries without issues 
      method:'GET',
      headers:{
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
      },

    }).then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson=>{
        setGetCountry(responseJson.data);
        setCountry_name(responseJson.data.country_name);
        setCountry_symbol(responseJson.data.symbol);
        //getBanksByCountry(country_symbol); //<== first place i used it, did not work
      })
  }


  useEffect(()=>{
    getallCountry();
  })

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <BackgroundOpacity
        display={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? false : modalVisible}
      />
      <View style={styles.space} />
      <ScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={{
          justifyContent: 'space-between',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        <ImageBackground
          source={{
            uri: 'asset:/logo/bg.JPG',
          }}
          imageStyle={{borderRadius: 6}}
          style={{
            top: -30,
            paddingTop: 95,
            alignSelf: 'center',
            width: 328,
            height: 115,
            borderadius: 9,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignSelf: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}>
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.accText}>Wallet Balance</Text>
            <Text style={styles.text}> 250,000 </Text>
          </View>
        </ImageBackground>

        <View
          style={{
            borderRadius: 5,
            borderWidth: 1,
            overflow: 'hidden',
            height: 53,
            padding: 0,
            borderColor: '#00BB23',
          }}>
          {
            <Picker
              style={{
                width: 300,
                height: 55,
                borderBottomWidth: 1,
              }}
              itemStyle={{
                fontSize: 25,
                fontFamily: 'Poppins-Medium',
              }}
              
              selectedValue={selectedCountry}
              onValueChange={(value, index) => setSelectedCountry(value)}
              >
              <Picker.Item label="Select Country" />
              {getCountry.map((country, index) => (
                <Picker.Item label={country.country_name} value={country.symbol} key={index} /> //<== country name works fine without problems
              ))}
            </Picker>
          }
        </View>
        
        <View style={styles.space}/>
        <View
          style={{
            borderRadius: 5,
            borderWidth: 1,
            overflow: 'hidden',
            height: 53,
            padding: 0,
            borderColor: '#00BB23',
          }}>
          {
            <Picker
              style={{
                width: 300,
                height: 55,
                borderBottomWidth: 1,
              }}
              itemStyle={{
                fontSize: 25,
                fontFamily: 'Poppins-Medium',
              }}
              selectedValue={selectedBank}
              onValueChange={(value, index) => setSelectedBank(value)}
              >
              <Picker.Item label="Select Bank" />
              {getBanks.map((bank, index) => (
                <Picker.Item label={bank.name} value={bank.code} key={index} /> //<== Does not return bank name here 
              ))}
            </Picker>
          }
        </View>
        
        <View style={styles.space2}/>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Destination Account"
          onChangeText={creditAccount => this.setState({creditAccount})}
          style={styles.input}
        />

        <TextInput
          placeholder=" Amount"
          onChangeText={amount => this.setState({amount})}
          style={styles.input}
        />

        <TextInput
          placeholder=" Narration"
          onChangeText={description => this.setState({description})}
          style={styles.input}
        />

        <TextInput
          placeholder=" Destination Branch Code"
          onChangeText={description => this.setState({description})}
          style={styles.input}
        />

        <TextInput
          placeholder=" Beneficiary Name"
          onChangeText={description => this.setState({description})}
          style={styles.input}
        />

        <View
          style={{
            borderRadius: 5,
            borderWidth: 1,
            overflow: 'hidden',
            height: 35,
            padding: 0,
            top: 10,
            borderColor: '#00BB23',
          }}>
          {
            <Picker
              style={{
                width: 300,
                height: 53,
                borderBottomWidth: 1,
              }}
              itemStyle={{
                fontSize: 25,
                fontFamily: 'Poppins-Medium',
              }}>
              <Picker.Item label="Currency" value="accNum" />
              <Picker.Item label="NGN" value="NGN" />
            </Picker>
          }
        </View>

        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            setModalVisible(true);
          }}
          style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={styles.loginbtn}> Transfer </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Modal
          hasBackdrop={true}
          backdropOpacity={0.2}
          backdropColor="black"
          transparent
          visible={modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => setModalVisible(false)}>
          <View style={styles.modal}>
            <Text>Hello From Modal</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <Text>Modal! Modal!</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </Modal>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};

export default InternationalPayments;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingTop: 40,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },

  modal: {
    top: '50%',
    height: '50%',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  accText: {
    top: -50,
    paddingTop: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-Medium',
    fontSize: 12,
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    top: -50,
    fontSize: 20,
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-Bold',
  },
  input: {
    top: 10,
    width: 300,
    height: 53,
    margin: 10,
    fontSize: 12,
    borderColor: '#00BB23',
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-Bold',
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 30,
  },

  button: {
    marginTop: 40,
    width: 150,
    height: 50,
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#00BB23',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },

  Regbutton: {
    width: 150,
    height: 52,
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#030303',
  },

  loginbtn: {
    color: '#ffff',
    fontSize: 15,
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-Medium',
  },

  AccountBalance: {
    fontSize: 13,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'left',
  },

  loginbtn2: {
    color: '#030303',
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },

  logo: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
  },

  space: {
    top: 10,
    width: 10,
    height: 20,
  },

  space2: {
    width: 10,
    height: 10,
  },

  imageStyle: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 5,
    margin: 2,
    height: 15,
    width: 15,
    resizeMode: 'stretch',
    marginBottom: 8,
    marginTop: 8,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

What must I do in this case? its not returning anything to the second Picker

Answer (score 0):

call `getBanksByCountry` function inside `useEffect` with `selectedCountry` as dependency (since you want to fetch the banks each time the country changes)

```
useEffect(()=>{
  getBanksByCountry(selectedCountry.symbol)
},[selectedCountry])
```

Answer (score 0):

After very intense struggle, i got it to work.
So here is what i Did

On the picker , i formally made it like so

```
<Picker
              style={{
                width: 300,
                height: 55,
                borderBottomWidth: 1,
              }}
              itemStyle={{
                fontSize: 25,
                fontFamily: 'Poppins-Medium',
              }}
              selectedValue={selectedCountry}
              onValueChange={(value, index) => [
                setSelectedCountry(value),
                getBanksByCountry(value), //<== I added the function to the picker vis Onchange since that is the function that handles the selection and all.
              ]}>
              <Picker.Item label="Select Country" />
              {getCountry.map((country, index) => (
                <Picker.Item
                  label={country.country_name}
                  value={country.symbol}
                  key={index}
                />
              ))}
            </Picker>
```

Next i made the getBanksByCountry(symbol) function to look like this

```
getBanksByCountry = async (symbol) => {
    if (symbol === 'GH') {
      fetch('https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/banks/GH', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization':
            'Bearer FLWSECK_TEST-72fe360edef17334f4817a17407011bb-X',
        },
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(async responseJson => {
          setGetBanks(responseJson.data);
          setBank_name(responseJson.data.name);
          setBank_code(responseJson.data.code);
        });

    }  if (symbol === 'UG') {
      fetch('https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/banks/UG', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization':
            'Bearer FLWSECK_TEST-72fe360edef17334f4817a17407011bb-X',
        },
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(async responseJson => {
          setGetBanks(responseJson.data);
          setBank_name(responseJson.data.name);
          setBank_code(responseJson.data.code);
        });
    }
    if (symbol === 'ZA') {
      fetch('https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/banks/ZA', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization':
            'Bearer FLWSECK_TEST-72fe360edef17334f4817a17407011bb-X',
        },
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(async responseJson => {
          setGetBanks(responseJson.data);
          setBank_name(responseJson.data.name);
          setBank_code(responseJson.data.code);
        });

    }  if (symbol === 'TZ') {
      fetch('https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/banks/TZ', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization':
            'Bearer FLWSECK_TEST-72fe360edef17334f4817a17407011bb-X',
        },
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(async responseJson => {
          setGetBanks(responseJson.data);
          setBank_name(responseJson.data.name);
          setBank_code(responseJson.data.code);
        });
    }
    
  };
```

Which in turn selects the country, so i just need to update my own REST api and have it communicate directly with the end servers and it gives me the required results :)
Hopefully this would be useful for someone someday :)